# Prove $(A\cap B ) \times (X \cap Y) = (A \times X) \cap (B \times Y) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove $(A\cap B ) \times (X \cap Y) = (A \times X) \cap (B \times Y) $?
where $A, B, X, Y$ are sets
This is an exercise in (Naive Set Theory) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZdEP.png)
The picture is my answer but I am not sure about my method.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think, your solution is fine

Comment: Your proof is good.

Answer (score 1):

If $(p,q) \in (A \cap B) \times (X \cap Y)$ then by definition $p \in A \cap B$ and $q \in X \cap Y$. So $(p,q) \in A \times X$ because in particular $p \in A$ and $q \in X$. Also $(p,q) \in B \times Y$ because $p \in B$ and $q \in Y$ also follows from the intersections. So $(p,q)$ is in the right hand set.

The reverse inclusion goes quite the same way. It basically comes down to the same argument you gave, but showing two inclusions is the normal way to proceed with such exercises.